# cannot convert parameter 2 from 'mxArray **' to 'mwArray &'

Tags: c++, matlab, c++-cli

I want to create a C++ Shared library from Matlab using deloytool and use it in MVS. I compile a function name 'foo.m', as the result I got list of files (.h,.cpp,.lib,...) and I found the function in 'fooCpplib.h' is as follow:

```
extern LIB_fooCpplib_CPP_API void MW_CALL_CONV foo(int nargout, mwArray& y, const mwArray& x);
```

Then I create a MVS project (2010), window form application, with 2 textbox and 2 click button, one textbox named inBox, and another named outBox. The code inside button_click is as follow:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
double input = System::Double::Parse(inBox->Text);
mxArray *x_ptr;
mxArray *y_ptr=NULL;
double *y;

// Create an mxArray to input into mlfFoo
x_ptr = mxCreateDoubleScalar(input);

// Call the implementation function 
// Note the second input argument should be &y_ptr instead of y_ptr. 
foo(1,&y_ptr,x_ptr);

// The return value from mlfFoo is an mxArray. 
// Use mxGetpr to get a pointer to data it contains.
y = (double*)mxGetPr(y_ptr);

// display the result in the form
outBox->Text = ""+*y;

//clean up memory
mxDestroyArray(x_ptr);
mxDestroyArray(y_ptr);
}
```

When I build the project, the error was occurred as below:

```
error C2664: 'foo' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'mxArray **' to 'mwArray &'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style
cast.
```

Note: I already included 'fooCpplib.h' in the .cpp source file.

Could anyone help me about this!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a parameter is declared as

```
TypeName &argName
```

it means that `argName` is a reference. In C++ you can pass parameters by reference, which allows the function modify the variable that you pass to it (among other things).

If you have a pointer, but a function expects a reference, you need to dereference the pointer in the call with an asterisk, rather than taking the address of a pointer with an ampersand:

```
foo(1,*y_ptr,*x_ptr);
//    ^      ^
//    |      |
//  Here and here
```

You can think of variables, pointers, pointers to pointers, etc. in terms of *level of indirection*. Variables have a level of indirection of zero; pointers have level of indirection of one; pointers to pointers have level of indirection of two, and so on.

Adding an ampersand increases the level of indirection; adding an asterisk decreases it. Like variables, references have level of indirection of zero. If you have a pointer and you need a variable, you must decrease the level of indirection by prepending an asterisk.

Another problem in your code is that `foo` expects references to `mwArray`, with a "w", but you are passing references to `mxArray`, with an "x". The types need to match, otherwise the compiler is not going to take your program.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I also try as you said by calling _italic_**bold**'foo(1,y_ptr,x_ptr);' but the result is same: cannot convert parameter 2 from 'mxArray *' to 'mwArray &'

Comment: @XuanThuongTran You need to add asterisks - it's not `foo(1,y_ptr,x_ptr);`, it is `foo(1,*y_ptr,*x_ptr);`

Comment: @XuanThuongTran One other thing, it looks like your method needs `mwArray`, with "w", but you have `mxArray`, with an "x". The types need to be the same.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the result is same: cannot convert parameter 2 from 'mxArray' to 'mwArray &'

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You've come at this purely from a C++ perspective. But  `mxArray*` should not be de-referenced since it's an opaque pointer. The advice you give solves the compilation problem the wrong way. The right way is to change `mxArray&` parameters to `mxArray*`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My assumption is that the targer API (i.e. the signature of `foo`) is beyond OP's control.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight My assumption was that Xuan is the author of `foo`. But looking again, I suspect you may be right.

Comment: I saw one comment said that, it's not meaningful to use mxArray&, and should using mxArray*. But, mxArray& was automatically generated by Matlab compiler when i complied function in Matlab to C++lib. So, would you tell me more about this issue. Or it means I should change mxArray& to mxArray* in 
    foo(int nargout, mwArray& y, const mwArray& x);

Comment: @XuanThuongTran David's comment would apply if you could influence the signature of `foo`, but since it is automatically generated by a tool, there is nothing you need to (or indeed, can) do about it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight@David Now, I see. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1):

`mwArray&` is a reference type. It's a "reference to `mwArray`". However, you're trying to pass `&y_ptr` which gives you a `mwArray**`, or a "pointer to pointer to `mwArray`". Instead, you should be dereferencing `y_ptr` to get a `mwArray` which you can pass by reference. The same is true for the third argument.

```
foo(1,*y_ptr,*x_ptr);
```

However, you have another problem, which is that `y_ptr` is null. You need it to be pointing at a `mwArray` object to dereference it.