# Dereference Pointer to MxArray

Tags: c, matlab, pointers, mex

I am confronting some pointer confusion:

I have some (Numerical Recipes) C-function `fitexy(in, &out)` that I would like to compile as a .mex file to call it from matlab. However, I can not get the gateway routine to access the *Pointer* to `out` so that it is passed to `plhs[0]`, how do I do that?

The closest I get (in the sense of the least confusing error message) is this:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){
float *in;
float out;

in      = (float *)mxGetData(prhs[0]);
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1,1,mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
out     = (float *)mxGetData(plhs[0]);

fitexy(in, &out);

printf("out = %lf", &out); /*Prints the correct result to the screen*/
}
```

This results in an error message on compiling:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float’ from type ‘float *’
```

Which in not too surprising to me, but not very helpful either. I tried to cast / dereference the output of `mxGetData(plhs[0])`,

```
out     = (float &)mxGetData(plhs[0]);
```

which seems to be kind of nonsense,

```
out     = (float)mxGetData(plhs[0]);
```

which conflicts with `out` being a variable and `mxGetData(plhs[0])` a pointer.

I already found [Save a variable (float *) to plhs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931805/save-a-variable-float-to-plhs) and [How to return a float value from a mex function, and how to retrieve it from m-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943953/how-to-return-a-float-value-from-a-mex-function-and-how-to-retrieve-it-from-m-f), but they both deal with casting rather than dereferencing .

I understand [cannot convert parameter 2 from 'mxArray **' to 'mwArray &'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374140/cannot-convert-parameter-2-from-mxarray-to-mwarray), but it does not help me, because I can not (i.e. would prefer not to) change the call to my C-routine.

Any help is warmly appreciated, thank a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just define `out` to be a pointer?

```
float * out;
```

This way you can easily do

```
out     = (float *)mxGetData(plhs[0]);
```

and you can use the `out` for writing a result value. If I am not mistaken about the `fitexy()` function, you can call it with

```
fitexy(in, out);
```

.

Comment: I just stuck to the original code where `out` was read from a file (needed to be copied to memory). Will accept your super swift answer after the time limit. Thank's a lot!

Comment: As @Amro pointed out, the subroutine must then be called as `fitexy(in, out);`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a C function `fit_line` with the following signature:

```
void fit_line(float x[], float y[], int n, float *a, float *b);
```

It takes two input data arrays `x` and `y` of length `n`, and fits a straight line `y = a*x + b` in the [least-squares sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) by computing the quatities `a` and `b`.

Here is how I would write the MEX function:

#### mex_fit_line.c

```c
#include "mex.h"

EXTERN_C void fit_line(float x[], float y[], int n, float *a, float *b);

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    /* validate inputs */
    if (nrhs!=2 || nlhs>2)
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "wrong num args");
    if (!mxIsSingle(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) || mxIsSparse(prhs[0]) ||
        !mxIsSingle(prhs[1]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[1]) || mxIsSparse(prhs[1]))
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "expecting dense real single arrays");
    if (mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]) != mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[1]))
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "length dont match");

    /* get data arrays */
    mwSize len = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
    float *x = (float*) mxGetData(prhs[0]);
    float *y = (float*) mxGetData(prhs[1]);
    if (x==NULL || y==NULL) mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:err", "null ptr");

    /* call external function */
    float a, b;
    fit_line(x, y, len, &a, &b);

    /* assign output */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    *((float*) mxGetData(plhs[0])) = a;
    if (nlhs>1) {
        plhs[1] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
        *((float*) mxGetData(plhs[1])) = b;
    }
}
```

After we compile it, we can call the MEX function from MATLAB as:

```matlab
% some random data
x = randn(100,1,'single');
y = -1.5*x + 1 + randn(size(x),class(x))*0.9;

% fit least-square line
[a,b] = mex_fit_line(x,y);

% plot data and fitted line
xx = linspace(min(x), max(x), 50);
yy = a*xx + b;
plot(x, y, 'b.')
line(xx,yy, 'Color','r')
axis equal, legend({'data', 'LS line'})
title(sprintf('y = %.2f*x + %.2f', a, b)), xlabel('X'), ylabel('Y')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That's a more complete answer. Yet -in my opinion- `*((float*) mxGetData(prhs[0])) = a;` looks a bit messy. `float *out = (float *)mxGetData(plhs[0]);` also does the trick.

Comment: well yeah, if you want to save a few variables, you can directly call the above function with: `fit_line(x, y, len, (float*) mxGetData(plhs[0]), (float*) mxGetData(plhs[1]));` (assuming you've create the output arrays prior to that) and get rid of `a` and `b` floats

Comment: @wsj: also I posted a complete example for a reason, in your case you have to call `fitexy(in, out);` **not** `fitexy(in, &out);` after doing `float *out = (float *)mxGetData(plhs[0]);`

Comment: You're right, otherwise it wouldn't compile. I added this to the accepted solution.